# How to monkey patch hijack method in GO language for unit test?

Tags: http, go

we have one handler function in which we're hijacking an incoming connection

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("ACK:"))
        hijacker, ok := w.(http.Hijacker)
        if !ok {
            http.Error(w, "hijacking not supported", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        clientConn, _, err := hijacker.Hijack()

        //[TODO] how to trigger this error?
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusServiceUnavailable)
            return
        }
        // do other stuff
    }
```

We need to write tests and the expectation is 100% code coverage. How do I trigger this error part when using `.Hijack` method?

I've tried

```
        oldHf := http.Hijacker.Hijack
        http.Hijacker.Hijack = func(net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error) (net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error) {
            return &net.TCPConn{}, &bufio.ReadWriter{}, errors.New("dummy error")
        }
        defer func() { http.Hijacker.Hijack = oldHf }()
```

But got this error

```
defer func() { http.Hijacker.Hijack = oldHf }()
http.Hijacker (type) is not an expressioncompilerNotAnExpr
cannot assign to http.Hijacker.Hijack (value of type func(http.Hijacker) (net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error))compilerUnassignableOperand
```

Comment: Pass your own ResponseWriter implementation to the method, which implements the Hijack method by returning an error.

Comment: http.Hijacker is an interface, so is http.ResponseWriter. Simply pass a custom implementation to the handler.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks for the input. I've been using the GO for the past few days, so please pardon if I sound stupid. To which function do I need to pass this ResponseWriter implementation?

Comment: Also take the Go Tour and learn the basics **before** you attempt things like "monkey patching". It is simply unreasonable to expect `http.Hijacker.Hijack = func...` to work given that `Hijacker` is a type.

Comment: *"To which function do I need to pass ..."* -- To the function under test.

Comment: @mkopriva but when I hover the cursor over the oldHF variable, it shows as a function instead of a type.

Comment: Did I say `oldHF` is a type?

Comment: @mkopriva Even the ```http.Hijacker.Hijack```  shows as  func (http.Hijacker).Hijack() (net.Conn, *bufio.ReadWriter, error). So, I'm not able to understand that why can not we update this with ```oldHF```

Comment: Did I say `http.Hijacker.Hijack` is a type?

Comment: You can update function values all you want Umesh. But you cannot, **at runtime**, modify **a type** in a **statically typed** language like Go. The Go language specification simply doesn't allow what you wish to do and the Go compiler that you are using to compile your program adheres to the specification. On top of that `http.Hijacker` (the type) is an interface type, which makes the `Hijack` method an **abstract method**; trying to set *that* to a function value is beyond reasonable, not only in statically typed languages.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for the input. Based on your comments, what I understand is that ```http.Hijack``` is a type. So, when the statement  ``` hijacker, ok := w.(http.Hijacker)``` is executed then at the runtime the  ```w```   variable's type is inferred from ```http.Hijacker```  type right? if that is the case, so the test function which invokes the main function should pass a custom ResponseWriter  having the implementation which supports the  ```Hijack``` method? sorry for the wrong terminologies

Comment: `w.(http.Hijacker)` is a **type assertion**, to learn about those read: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/N_6pctixO2o

Comment: @mkopriva thanks a lot! I noticed that ```r.Header.Get("key")``` statement beaks into my code when I use the snippet from the playground link